# Does Mandrill automatically retry soft-bounces?

Tags: mandrill

If i send an email with Mandrill, and get a "rejected" status back the reason was a "soft-bounce", do Mandrill automatically retry to send the email again after a certain period of time, or do i have to send it myself in my own program again after some time?

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33191720/8862954, Mandrill doesn't deal with soft bounces, because it depends on the individual mailboxes.

Other bounces, according to [MD's docs](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582937-About-Bounces), are handled by adding the email to the rejection list so MD doesn't keep retrying sends to that address.